# libGDX pixelated rendering

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am a beginner with lib GDX, I am following one of their tutorials in order to learn basics.

I have a set of around 400 images out of which I create a `.png` and `.atlas` files. The resolution of these images is 128*256

I have the following code to render it on a Nexus 5 device:

```
public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private TextureAtlas textureAtlas;
    private Sprite sprite;
    private int currentFrame = 1;
    private String currentAtlasKey = new String("0001");

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/packOne.atlas"));
        TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion region = textureAtlas.findRegion("0001");
        sprite = new Sprite(region);



        sprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - sprite.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - sprite.getHeight() / 2);
      //  sprite.scale(2.5f);
        Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                currentFrame++;
                if (currentFrame > 393)
                    currentFrame = 1;

                // ATTENTION! String.format() doesnt work under GWT for god knows why...
                currentAtlasKey = String.format("%04d", currentFrame);
                sprite.setRegion(textureAtlas.findRegion(currentAtlasKey));
            }
        }
                , 0, 1 / 30.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        textureAtlas.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        sprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

When I use `sprite.scale(2.5f);` the images are scaled but pixelated and when I dont use it, the images dont seem pixelated but are rendered very small. I want this sequence to be full screen without pixelation. How can I improve on this? Should I just go for a higer res images such as 512 * 1024. I want this to function normally on all multiple screen sizes.

Comment: Absolutely you need to start with a higher resolution image if you want it bigger on the screen. And set the texture atlas to use a minFilter of MipMapLinearNearest and magFilter of Linear. Also, read up on Viewports for handling different screen sizes: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports And here's a good article on how to size objects in a 2D game: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/pixels/

Comment: Thank you, I'll go through these now :)

Comment: I think I will go with ScreenViewport, any help you can offer me in implementing that, with the above program logic?

Comment: The instructions are all at that link. You can post another question here if you follow the directions and still have problems. Also, ScreenViewport is the only option that is always wrong, in my opinion. It does nothing to handle different screen sizes. ExtendViewport is the right choice for probably 90% of cases.

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04 you've been a savior :) I will look into that